# Read JSON with Retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I tried to read my Json but I don't know how to map this json response in their basic element.

and This is how my Json look like:

```
    [
      {
       12345: {
           L Hendrik: {
             CU.Administration ID: "12345_LJ",
             CU.Customer ID: "L Hendrik",
             CU.Name: "Coffeecompany L Hendrik"
             }
          }
]
```

"12345" is a dynamic id,
"L Hendrik" is a dynamic name

My code:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("URLTOMYAPI")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
    Call<List<Student>> call = service.getStudentDetails();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Student>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Student>> call, Response<List<Student>> response) {
            List<Student> students = response.body();

            String details = "";

            for(int i = 0; i<students.size(); i++){
                String name = students.get(i).getName();

                details += "\n\nname: " + name;
            }
            textDetails.setText(details);
            pDialog.hide();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Student>> call, Throwable t) {
            pDialog.hide();
            Log.v("Test", "Failluree?");

            Log.v("Test", "Failluree?" + t);

        }
    });
```

And my Pojo

```
public class Student implements Serializable {

    private String name, address, custId;
    private int mobile;

    public String getCustId() {
        return custId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I know the Pojo is not correct, but I don't know how to get the information from this Json.

Comment: Since your keys are dynamic you should get the response as a string and then use the built in `JSONObject` class to parse it and then iterate over it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you cannot parse Json by `GSON`， you should parse Json manually. like this:

```
APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
Call<JSONArray> call = service.getStudentDetails();

call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JSONArray> call, Response<JSONArray> response) {
        for(int idx = 0; idx < response.length(); idx++) {
           JSONObject jsonObject = response.get(idx);
           Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
           while (keys.hasNext()) {
           JSONObject object = jsonObject.optJSONObject(keys.next()).getJSONObject("L Hendrik");
                if (object != null) {
                    Student student = new Student();
                    student.setName(object.optString("CU.Administration ID"));
                    // Other parse .   
                }
           }
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Student>> call, Throwable t) {
        pDialog.hide();
        Log.v("Test", "Failluree?");

        Log.v("Test", "Failluree?" + t);

    }
});
```

Comment: @AlfaLaurens try this

Comment: @AlfaLaurens you can change `JsonObject` to `JsonArray`, then read all object.

Comment: But JsonArray don't have keys?